# How to use DBA_JOBS in procedure

Tags: database, oracle, ora-00942

I want to make sendmsg when deadjob. 
So I need `DBA_JOBS` select in procedure
How can i use `DBA_JOBS` in procedure
I trying for this code :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM DBA_JOBS
 WHERE JOB in('539','639','679','719','919','1359');
```

But this error block my new procedure

> ***ORA-00942*** table or view does not exist

Comment: How do you know if a Job is running (i.e. dead)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly give read permission to this view.

```
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Dec 4 08:15:47 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> grant select on dba_jobs to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be granted for `dba_jobs` view that's needed for the usage through the whole database. Use `user_jobs` view instead :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count
  FROM USER_JOBS
 WHERE JOB in('539','639','679','719','919','1359');
```